# forEach function in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, foreach

I am working with graphql returned data that looks like this:

```
"userRelations": [
    {
      "relatedUser": {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Miller"
      },
      "type": "FRIEND"
    },
    {
      "relatedUser": {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Rhena",
        "lastName": "Tahoma"
      },
      "type": "CONTACT"
    }
  ]
```

I had to separate all those items which had the `type: "FRIENDS"`. I did this and it worked perfectly:

```
    var friendArray = new Array();
    for (let i in data.users.nodes[0].userRelations) { 
    if (data.users.nodes[0].userRelations[i].type == "FRIEND")
    {
        friendArray.push(data.users.nodes[0].userRelations[i]);
    }
  }
```

However, I read that using for loops and for in is not a good idea. Is there any other way to iterate and check all the objects without for loops? I tried using this but it doesn't give the correct results:

```
data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.forEach((object: Object)=> {
    if (data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.type == "FRIEND")
    {
        friendArray.push(data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.object);
    }
})
```

The friendsArray remains empty. What am I missing out?

Edit: 
After filtering the friends data, I want to render some items by mapping. I was trying to do something like this:

```
data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map()
```

```
data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter(({ type }) => type === 'FRIEND').map(/*code*/)
```

but this gave me an error that:

```
Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
```

Comment: Have a look at array.filter(), you can do `const friends = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter(userRelation => userRelation.type === 'FRIEND")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use `filter`:

```
var result = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter(element=>element.type=="FRIEND");
```

Comment: This gives me ```This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)``` in typescript.

Comment: You’ve got a typo `=>` not `->`

Comment: Still, this gives me ```Parameter 'element' implicitly has an 'any' type.```If I infer parameters from usage, it changes to ```element: { type: string; }```. Originally, the type is ```UserRelation```that I have defined myself. However, that doesn't work either.

Comment: ```((element: { type: UserRelation; }) => element.type=="FRIEND");```gives me the same error as in my first comment

Comment: What about `var result = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter((element: UserRelation)=>element.type==="FRIEND");` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.forEach((o: Object)=> {
    if (o.type == "FRIEND")
    {
        friendArray.push(o);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using a for loop there is fine.

If you want to use foreach, you'll need to use the object element you create in the forEach callback. That's the advantage of using foreach.

```js
data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.forEach((object: Object)=> {
    if (object.type == "FRIEND")
    {
        friendArray.push(object);
    }
})
```

If you want to improve the function, you may want to use a [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which is probably the cleanest way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at array.filter(), you can do `const friends = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter(userRelation => userRelation.type === 'FRIEND")` but to your current code, you could change your if statement to be - `if(object.type==='FRIEND')`

Comment: doesn't work in TS, even after I define the type for userRelation